# Convert array of timestamps in PostgreSQL (not in a table)

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to get this command:

```
SELECT '2021-02-17 13:46:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'
     , '2021-02-26 13:46:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'
```

to work for an array (or in rows). Reason is that I have a lot of timestamps that need to be converted and if I use the above structure, I just end up adding lots of columns that my front-end can't handle.

My current solution is to actually dump all of the timestamps into a table and use the `set timezone ='';` command to set different timezones before I insert and before I select. Because of how often I have to do this request, I want to ideally use an array for the above command, so that I don't need a dummy table, but also don't have my results split into a new column each. I've tried the `timezone()` function, but that one didn't like arrays either. For both, I tried to "tell" psql that I'm inputting an array using various permutations of `timestamptz []`, but none have worked and I wonder if both of these methods just don't allow for what I want to do?

Alternatively I'd be happy with output in rows as well.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: `select unnest(ARRAY['02/24/2021 14:25'::timestamp, '02/25/2021 9:56'::timestamp]) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind multiple rows, then does this work for you?

```
select ts::timestamp at time zone 'America/Denver' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'
  from unnest(array['2021-02-17 13:46:00','2021-02-26 13:46:00']) as u(ts);
```

If it needs to be an array:

```
select array_agg(ts::timestamp at time zone 'America/Denver' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin')
  from unnest(array['2021-02-17 13:46:00','2021-02-26 13:46:00']) as u(ts);
```